# Empty class with comment same as pass?

Tags: python

Are these equivalent?

```
class Empty : pass
```

and

```
class Empty:
    '''
    This class intentionally left blank
    '''
```

The second one seems better for readability and one could put `pass` at the end but it does not seem necessary.

Is the comment treated as a `pass`?

Comment: It's a misconception that that's a comment. Comments start with `#`. What you have there is a string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your two codes are *almost* equivalent, but not quite. [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) is just a no-op. The docstring is almost a no-op as well, but it adds a `__doc__` attribute to your class object, so there is a small difference.

A version that would be functionally equivalent to using `pass` would be to use [`Ellipsis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) a.k.a. `...`:

```
class Empty: ...
```

There is nothing special about `...` in this case. Any pre-existing object that you don't assign will work just as well. For example, you could replace `...` with `None`, `1`, `True`, etc. The choice of `...` is a popular alternative because it is much more aesthetically pleasing. By convention, it means a stub that is to be filled in, while `pass` usually indicates a deliberate no-op.

Using `...` like that will raise a `SyntaxError` in Python 2. You can use the named `Ellipsis` object instead, but that is not nearly as pretty.

You may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36622334/2988730) about the equivalence of `pass` and `return None` in functions interesting.

Comment: Why would you use `Ellipsis` rather than say a boolean or integer or anything else you throw away? Wouldn't `None` be most equivalent?

Comment: @Chris_Rands. No particular reason, but it's semi conventional at this point. Using a particular value implies code or a return value or something, and just generally looks wrong. Ellipsis seems to look right. I'll find a source or two for that.

Comment: You should also note that Python 2 considers using an ellipsis instead of `pass` that a `SyntaxError`—so the former is more version independent.

Comment: @martineau. Added. Interesting that `...` is an error but `Ellipsis` is not. Is it being treated like `:` outside `[]`?

Comment: I think the syntax difference is due to the fact that `Ellipsis` had a more limited role in Python 2 where it was used only for something called "extended slicing syntax" which is meaningless as a standalone statement.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, I didn't know Raymond and others were promoting this, I see the readability aspect but it's not intuitive if you know what the `Ellipsis` is actually used for normally. Also only using `None` provides equivalent Cpython bytcode to using `pass`

Answer (score 4):

No, they're not equivalent.

Since the implementation of [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#specification), if the first expression in a module, function, or class is a string, that string will be assigned to that module/function/class's `__doc__` attribute:

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in
>   a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring
>   becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.

*Functionally*, the classes are equivalent. However, the difference between having a docstring and not having a docstring can surface when you're creating documentation for your code. Tools like [sphinx-autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html) can pick up the docstring and generate documentation for your class, and you'll end up with something like this in your documentation:

> *class* **Empty()**
>
> This class intentionally left blank

For this reason, it's generally preferable not to use a docstring for this kind of thing. Instead, it would be better to use a comment:

```
class Empty:
    pass  # This class intentionally left blank
```