# Where did the "None"s come from? | Python map() function

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return, map-function

I wrote a little code that uses the map() function:

```
def function(a):
if a % 2 == 0:
    return a
else: 
    pass
x = map(function, (1,3,2,5,6))
print(set(x))
```

It's supposed to return every even number that is provided, If it's an odd number, I don't want it to return anything, so I put "pass". However, when I run it, the output goes like this:

> {2, 6, None}

This is weird, I'm not sure where the "None" came from, and when I change the set() function that is used to print the X to either list() or tuple(), the output goes like these:

> [None, None, 2, None, 6] or (None, None, 2, None, 6)

I'm not really sure what's going on here, the odd numbers weren't supposed to return anything but instead, it's still there as "None". Is there a way I could fix this? What caused this in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["pass" same as "return None" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622334/pass-same-as-return-none-in-python) See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Python function returns something. If no `return` statement is executed, or the `return` statement has no expression, then the function returns `None`. And that's where your `None`s come from.

If you want to filter a list of values by some criterion, write a function which returns True or False (or equivalents), and use the `filter` built-in:

```py
>>> def isEven(a):
...     return a % 2 == 0

>>> [*filter(isEven, (1,3,2,5,6))]
[2, 6]
```

`[*generator]` turns a generator into a list. That also works with sets, using `{*generator}`; for tuples, you need a trailing comma: `(*generator,)`. (Thanks, @MustafaAydin.)